# Sum of time worked per team, preventing double counting when teams change

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, I am working on a measure with the time worked for each team in a certain period.

I have a table "Employees", which simply contains the [Employee ID] and [Name].

I have another table "Employee data, which contains the [team] and [function] of each employee. Since teams and functions can change each month, i have a column [date]. For example, in a 6 month period, each employee would have 6 lines (one for each month).
Finally, I have the table "Time registration" which contains the columns [Employee ID], [date] and [minutes worked].

The relationships are as follows:
**Employee data** -[Employee ID]-(both directions)-> **Employees** -[Employee ID]-> **Time registration**

When I create a table with [Team] and [minutes worked], there are more minutes worked in some teams than there should be.
After some digging, it turns out that when an employee changes team, PowerBI sums their minutes worked twice:
[image: Example of problem in PowerBI]

In this example, the total of minutes worked is 13000 minutes. When showing the Sum of Minutes worked per team, it appears to total 13000. However, when you sum the minutes worked of each team together (2169+5575+5123+6541) you get 19408.
In the third table, you see how PowerBI has two rows for employees who've switched teams, and thus their minutes worked are counted double.

How can I avoid this behavior, so that I can get an accurate sum of minutes worked per team?

I have created sample data and a sample PowerBI file that shows the issue: [Link to Google Drive with sample data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XTmM279DKq8VhHUzLw7V2-8GUQ7IxTs4?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide sample raw data in the same schema as your tables.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks for the suggestion. I should have done that to start with. I've included sample data and gave a much better example of the issue.